# how to convert smart quotes to plain text in JSP

Tags: jsp, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

I have a scenario wherein i copy data from a MS Word or outlook and paste it into a JSP textarea and then try to presist the same onto Oracle database using Spring and Hibernate as well. the problem is the following sentence

**It’s not the only character, we also allow – and -- also**

gets replaced to

It���s not the only character, we also allow ��� and -- also.

Can anyone please let me know as to how i can persist the actual data into the table.

**Note:** If i type in ' and - into the textarea and persist, they get saved without any problem. Problem occurs only when i copy text from word/outlook and paste them into the text area.

I have tried to put the following into my JSP, but doesn't help me in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Solved the same by following the below mentioned steps.

1. Retained the following section

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   ```

in the head section of the JSP. Have removed the < tag before the meta tag .

2. Added the UTF-8 enforcer in my Web.xml. Following piece of code was used.

   ```
   <filter>

       <filter-name>encodingFilter/filter-name>

       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter/filter-class>

       <init-param>

           <param-name>encoding/param-name>

           <param-value>UTF-8/param-value>

       </init-param>

       <init-param>

           <param-name>forceEncoding/param-name>

           <param-value>true/param-value>

       </init-param>

   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>

       <filter-name>encodingFilter/filter-name>

       <url-pattern>/*/url-pattern>

   </filter-mapping>
   ```
3. Made used of a utility to convert the smart quotes to plain text. The utility I used is stated below (Took reference from http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?72944-How-to-handle-Smart-Quotes-pasted-into-TextArea-input). Thanks to RobertGloverJr for posting that part of the solution.

   ```
   public static void windows1252ToIso8859(StringBuilder sbOriginal)  {
         if (null==sbOriginal) {
            return;
         }
         for (int isb = 0; isb < sbOriginal.length(); isb++)  {
            int origCharAsInt = (int) sbOriginal.charAt(isb);
            switch (origCharAsInt) {

            case ((int)'\u2018'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '\''); break;  // left single quote
            case ((int)'\u2019'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '\''); break;  // right single quote
            case ((int)'\u201A'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '\''); break;  // lower quotation mark

            case ((int)'\u201C'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '"'); break;  // left double quote
            case ((int)'\u201D'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '"'); break;  // right double quote
            case ((int)'\u201E'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '"'); break;  // double low quotation mark

            case ((int)'\u2039'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '\''); break;  // Single Left-Pointing Quotation Mark
            case ((int)'\u203A'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '\''); break;  // Single right-Pointing Quotation Mark

            case ((int)'\u02DC'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '~'); break;  // Small Tilde

            case ((int)'\u2013'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '-'); break;  // En Dash
            case ((int)'\u2014'):  sbOriginal.setCharAt(isb, '-'); break;  // EM Dash

            default: break;
            }
         }
      }

      public static String windows1252ToIso8859(String strOriginal)  {
         if (null==strOriginal) {
            return null;
         }
         StringBuilder sbOrig = new StringBuilder(strOriginal);
         windows1252ToIso8859(sbOrig);
         return sbOrig.toString();
      }
   ```
4. Finally changed my setter method of the DAO layer to use the above mentioned utility as shown below.

   ```
   public String getIncidentShrtDescC() {
       return this.incidentShrtDescC;
   }

   public void setIncidentShrtDescC(String incidentShrtDescC) {
       this.incidentShrtDescC = AppGlobalUtil.windows1252ToIso8859(incidentShrtDescC);
   }
   ```

Combination of all of the above helped in resolving the issue. Hope this post helps some wandering soul facing the same problem.

Happy Coding.